# NSSearchField: how to clear selection (set selected range)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I can select all text in a NSSearchField by invoking its ***selectText:*** message (which is probably meant for the "Select All" menu item).

But how do I clear the selection, e.g. set the text cursor to the edit field's end, after I've set the text field with ***setStringValue:***? (Note: ***setStringValue:*** selects the text automagically, which I don't want.)

I've tried invoking ***setSelectedRange:*** but that message is not understood by NSSearchField instances, it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
[[self.searchField currentEditor] moveToEndOfLine:nil];
```

Comment: There's one uglyness left, though: I can't simply call setStringValue and then invoke your code right after - that still ends up selecting the entire input line if the searchfield did not have the focus before. Would you know how to deal with this without having to set a flag and then do your call in the didBeginEditing callback? I mean, is there some way to suppress the automatic selection of all text when I set the text and give the focus to the search field?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: I cant try as now I dont have mac/xcode with me. I can only check tomorrow morning i.e. 12hrs from now.

Comment: _Please don't just say you found a solution without posting it! :-(_
_I have the exact same problem as you and I'm trying to figure out a solution: could you please share with us how you managed to fix the problem? It would help me, as well as other people having this issue an googling for a solution :-)_
Nevermind: I didn't realize your solution was the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I should have just googled instead of asking here. The solution is hinted at on this site: http://rchampourlier.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/how-to-partially-select-content-of-a-nstextfield/

I need to get the "current editor", like this:

```
NSText *textEditor = [searchField currentEditor];
NSRange range = {start, length};
[textEditor setSelectedRange:range];
```